# Pagecurl effect in html

Tags: jquery, html, turnjs

i am looking for a pagecurl effect in html very similar to http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs . But i am specifically looking for the similar effect on a single page also if i could change the dimensions according to my requirement.
    I have refered to jflip plugin but i am not able to customise it according to my requirement. Please refer to the below images.

Is there any jquery plugin available apart from turnjs or jFlip which I can use or any other possible solution?

Page curl image:

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2pttl5e.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Turn.js [documentation](http://www.turnjs.com/turnjs4-api-docs.pdf) making the catalog a single page is as simple as declaring:

```
    $('#magazine').turn({ display:'single' });
```

To alter the style of the page-fold you can modify either the `_fold` function or permanently adjusting the `point2d` objects that are passed into it whenever it's called.

```
        //Lines ~2672 and ~2972
        c.x = Math.round(v[0]);
        c.y = Math.round(v[1]); //increase or decrease height
        flipMethods._fold.call(that, c);
```